# Typescript React component decorator

Tags: typescript, decorator

It might be a rookie mistake, but I'm trying to create a simple class decorator using typescript for a React component, like this:

```
import * as React from 'react'

interface Greeter {
  sayHello: boolean
}

const greet = (arg: Greeter) => (Comp: React.Component) => {
  // do some stuff
}

@greet({ sayHello: true })
class MyComp extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    return <div>Hi</div>
  }
}
```

But I'm getting a compile error saying

> Argument of type 'typeof MyComp' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'Component<{}, {}>'.

What exactly am I doing wrong here? Am I missing something with the decorator syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're passing the class to `greet`, rather than an object of that class, add a `typeof`:

```
const greet = (arg: Greeter) => (Comp: typeof React.Component) => {
  // do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when this was added, but in newer versions of `@types/react` you can also do `React.ComponentType` e.g.

```
const greet = (arg: Greeter) => (Comp: React.ComponentType) => {
  // do some stuff
}
```